# Did anyone tried to get Illuminator badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

So basically, let's put it like this. Did anyone tried to get this badge? So, I've done the math to see if it's possible.

So, it says:

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer
>   score > 0)

That's 720 minutes. Which means that to get this done, you need to post 1 answer in 1.44 minutes or else you'll fail in getting it. That means that I need to read a question and write a good answer in that small period of time.

So, I'm done with some projects that I had, day job is day job, and I was thinking to get one day off from everything and try to do this. Just to see if it's possible.

I'd go through unanswered questions, and try to answer as much as I can in 12 hours.

But, I'm interested in approach, because I don't like to give small one lined answers, but rather detailed answers, so my question for you all is...

Did anyone tried to do this action? What approach would you have for getting that badge?

Comment: I have never thought in terms of points and badges. I just do what I do and let what happens happen. However, the other day I was poking around looking at badges and found this particular badge interesting. It is funny that you should ask about it. It was the only badge that I really took a look at with any thought. It seemed, at the time, like it would be nearly impossible to get unless on a more busy site. Thanks for asking! It is good to see the answers. They cleared up my confusion. Cheers mate!!

Answer (score 9):

> Which means that to get this done, you need to post 1 answer in 1.44 minutes or else you'll fail in getting it.

No, you have 12 hours to edit and answer a *single question*. You can take as many minutes (or more realistically, "years"!) to answer all 500 questions in this fashion to get the badge!

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

"both actions" refers to editing and answering a single question within a 12 hour period. You need to do this 500 times to get the badge, and you don't need to do this consecutively.

For example, you could *edit* a question at 8am. Then answer the same question at 7pm (11 hours later - the same 12 hour period). A *week later* you could do the same thing. Providing both answers have been upvoted then you have 2/500 towards your goal - still a long way to go! Keep going!

No one has got this badge yet! (Although I think one or two are getting close!)

But there are bronze and silver badges that you'll get before this, if you haven't already.

Comment: sry, I don't understand this one. So, i need to edit/answer question every 12hours?

Comment: Not "every" 12 hours. It doesn't need to be consecutive. Just edit and answer a question in any 12 hour period (which then gets upvoted), and do this 500 times (over a long period of time)! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now I get it! Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can take years to answer the 500 questions.   When you answer any particular question you have to edit the question at the same time (within 12 hours of answering) for it to count towards the badge.

This is to prevent people from going back and mass editing lots of questions that they already answered just to get the badge.

The [illuminator badge was announced in September 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator).  The thread in meta announcing it has a lot more info about the requirements for it and the rational for creating it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I see that you are close to it :)

Comment: Its a tough badge to get.   At the point it was announced, I had not made a habit of editing questions I answered unless they were absolutely awful.  It has certainly prompted me to make more edits.